# Find the rate of change in height of water level.

Tags: calculus

A cone shaped container has a diameter of $0.6m$ and height of $0.5m$. Water is poured into the container with a constant rate of $0.2m^{3}s^{-1}$.

Calculate the rate of change in height of the water level when its height reaches $0.4m$.

Ok, so $\frac {dV}{dt} = 0.2$

V = $\frac 1 3 \pi r^2h$

I want to find $\frac {dh}{dt}$

so can it be found by doing this?

$\frac {dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dh} . \frac{dh}{dt}$

if so, then how can $\frac {dV}{dh}$ be calculated?

$\frac {dV}{dh} = \frac1 3 \pi r^2$

This is as far as I can go. I don't know the value of $r$ when the height is $0.4m$.

**Update:**

Since $\tan \theta = \frac {0.3}{0.5}$

$\theta = \tan^{-1} 0.6 = 30.96$

When, $ h = 0.4$

$r = \tan (30.96) \times 0.4 = 0.24$

$\frac {dV}{dh} = \frac 1 3 \pi (0.24)^2 = 0.0603$

So, $\frac {dh}{dt} = \frac{0.2}{0.0603} = 3.316$

But the real answer is $1.105$. Could it be that $\frac{dV}{dh} = \pi r^2$ and not $\frac 1 3 \pi r^2$ ? Or have I made some seriously wrong calculations?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: @5xum yeah, should've done that the first time. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: to find r when the height is 0.4 m, it would be useful to draw a picture. You know that the base of the cone has diameter 0.6m (radius 0.3) and height 0.5m. You can use some elementary trig to find the radius at the desired height.

Comment: To find r you can appy the intercept theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem The ratio of the heights is equal to the ratio of diameters.

Comment: @MacCab Okay, thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using similar triangles, we have that $\frac{r}{h}=\frac{.3}{.5}$, so $r=\frac{3}{5}h$.

Then $\displaystyle V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h=\frac{\pi}{3}\big(\frac{3}{5}h\big)^2h=\frac{3\pi}{25}h^3,\;\;$ so $\displaystyle\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{9\pi}{25}h^2\frac{dh}{dt}$.

When $h=.4$, this gives $\displaystyle.2=\frac{9\pi}{25}\big(.4\big)^2\frac{dh}{dt},\;\;$ so $\displaystyle\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{125}{36\pi}\approx1.105 \;m/s$

Comment: You're much help. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad that helped.